# How do I simulate Windows 8 RT in VS 2012?

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, simulator

Visual Studio 2012 has a wonderful simulator built in for creating Windows 8 apps.  However, it appears that when I run it, it's running another light instance of my own PC (including start up programs).

[image]

[image: Metro UI Expereince]

Windows 8 RT is a different experience without the desktop.  Is it possible, and if so how do I simulate the Windows 8 RT experience within the Visual Studio 2012 simulation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Windows 8 RT is a different experience without the desktop

Well no, [Windows RT still has the desktop mode tacked it](http://www.theverge.com/2012/8/31/3281960/windows-rt-office-2013-rt-specs-details-hands-on) and what the simulator offers, is pretty much what you see in the RT.

> Overall, the desktop functionality on Windows RT is very similar to its Windows 8 counterpart — but ARM-based systems are clearly designed to be used in the new Windows 8 Start Screen.

Comment: I didn't realize the Win RT has a version of the desktop on it...  However, it only comes with pre-installed applications, which the simulator isn't simulating.  I guess my question is whether or not there's a difference between the two, and if so, is there a way to simulate that difference?

Comment: @KronoS I don't see why the difference should make any difference? I'll see what I can find anyway.

Comment: From my understandings (obviously this is difficult since I do not have an RT system myself to play with) is that ARM compiled metro apps are made ARM compatible at compile time, but programmatically function exactly the same as their Win8 counterparts.
Thus, simulating a Modern UI app in VS (even though it looks like a win8 pro system) will still generate the same results as a test in RT.

Comment: @JaredTritsch - You are correct.  The only question is that of performance.  You could of course also say this of any `Android` or `iPhone` phone.  In that a iPhone 4s will be slower then an iPhone 5 on the same version of the iOS platform.